# How will iOS enforce connections to use a secure connection exclusively?

Tags: ios, security, tcp, udp, tls1.2

Starting 2017, [Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/). Apps will be forced to use ATS, based on TLS, to establish a connection successfully.

I'm currently developing a network measurement tool for a client. Using the low-level socket interfaces, the purpose is to transmit packets over TCP or UDP to a server in the network, in order to measure the speed of the WiFi connection.

As it is not clear how Apple will enforce their new rules, we find it hard to estimate how our application will be influenced by them. Is there any more information available on this? On which types of connections do they apply? Based on what characteristics will iOS label a connection as insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should be fine. See this thread with a response from an Apple staff: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979

The relevant part:

> First up, there have been no changes to the technical behaviour of ATS (other than the addition of NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent and NSRequiresCertificateTransparency).  From a technical perspective, ATS exceptions in the newly seeded OS releases work the same way as they do in the current OS release.
>   What has changed is that App Review will require “reasonable justification” for most ATS exceptions.  The goal here is to flush out those folks who, when ATS was first released, simply turned it off globally and moved on.  That will no longer be allowed.